# What is the alternative to getTranslationY() method in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-listfragment

The following error throws in pre-honeycomb version. Error Log in my App,shows as follows :

```
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.getTranslationY
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at com.quickreturntopanimation.AnimationFragment$2.onScroll(AnimationFragment.java:135)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:675)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2956)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2065)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3315)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-06 11:48:32.563: E/AndroidRuntime(433):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Error shows in this line :

```
if(mQView.getTranslationY() != 0) {
```

Any Help Appreciated.........Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't exist before Honeycomb, so you can't call it.  You need to find a way to do it without calling that function.

Comment: I need to get translatedY position. What is the Solution?

Comment: What is the alternative to that?

Comment: I don't think there is anything.  It was new functionality for version 11.  You may be able to replicate it on your own by keeping track of it by hand, but its a bit of work to do that.  Or depending on the app you may just be able to cut this feature for pre-honeycomb devices.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use NineOldAndroid. According to its Docs

> NineOldAndroid library includes compatibility implementations of almost all of the new properties which were introduced with Android 3.0 allowing you to perform very complex animations that work on every API level.

You can find it here -> [NineOldAndroid](http://nineoldandroids.com/#usage)